# In 2015, did the Israeli Defence Force execute an elderly Palestinian woman, Ghalia Abu Reida, after taking a picture with her?

Tags: military, israel, palestine

[Warning: The links below contain distressing images of the result of violence.]

X/Twitter account [@HoyPalestina](https://twitter.com/HoyPalestina/status/1724516321101074717) posted a tweet on 15 November 2023, claiming:

> In 2015, Israeli army spokesman Avichai Adraee posted a photo of an Israeli soldier “serving water to an elderly Palestinian woman.”
>
> Journalists later revealed that the soldier shot the disabled elderly woman, who was identified as Ghalia Abu Reida.
>
> The soldier murdered her right after the photo.[Google translated]

Attached is a 2015 screenshot from Avichai Adraee Arabic Twitter/X account posting a picture of a frail elderly woman accepting water from an armed uniformed man, and a second picture of the same woman's corpse.

Meanwhile X/Twitter account [@QudsNen](https://twitter.com/QudsNen/status/1723823289347235928) ("QNN" -- [Quds News Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quds_News_Network)) posted a tweet on 13 Nov 2023 claiming:

> [...]
> In 2015, the spokesperson for the Israeli army Avichai Adraee published a photo of an Israeli soldier serving water to an old Palestinian woman.
> Journalists revealed afterward that the soldier shot the disabled old woman, who was identified as Ghalia Abu Reida, right after taking the picture with her.

Is this story true?

Comment: The Q seems reasonable, but I warn you that self-answers are being treated harshly here on topics like this, especially when posted right after the Q.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not seem that there was any further investigation by the Israeli officials about the incident, so there is no really any concrete proof or evidence that the IDF executed her, however, we know that the IDF met and took a photo with her and that there was a women who has been killed in 04 August 2014 in the IDF invasion (see [PCHR report](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811062221/http://www.pchrgaza.org/portal/en/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10562:on-the-28th-day-of-the-israeli-offensive-israeli-forces-redeploy-in-invaded-areas-in-the-gaza-strip-complete-neighborhoods-destroyed-11-palestinian-civilians-including-5-children-killed-by-israeli-bombardment-of-unrwa-shelter-in-rafah&catid=36:pchrpressreleases&Itemid=194)).

There is also a UN report [here](https://www.un.org/unispal/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/cb361dbaf1526e5785257e6c004b1e94_20150622%20--%20OHCHR%20Report%20on%20Palestine%20%5BA_HRC_CRP_4%5D.pdf) about the incident supports the claims that the woman spotted in the IDF picture is the same one found dead later:

> 333. The case of Ghalia Abu Reda: A witness told the commission that he and his family decided to leave their home in Khuza’a in accordance
>      with the warnings issued by the IDF prior to the launch of the ground
>      operation. As attacks were intensifying, they fled Khuza’a in a state
>      of complete panic, leaving behind one of the family members, Ghalia
>      Abu Reda, a woman aged about 70, in a wheelchair. Ghalia Abu Reda’s
>      cousin stayed
>      behind, in order to look after her for as long as possible, but
>      eventually the cousin too was compelled to leave. When the witness
>      returned to the family home a few days later, he found Ghalia Abu
>      Reda’s dead body. She had a bullet mark in her head and blood on her
>      face. The doctor who later examined the body told the witness that she
>      had been shot from close range, from a distance of about two metres.
>      Another member of the Abu Reda family confirmed the above allegations
>      to the commission. That witness stated that the house was very close
>      to the Green Line and that, some days or weeks later, an Israeli
>      soldier posted on twitter a picture of another IDF soldier offering
>      water to Ghalia Abu Reda:
>
> *“The soldiers did this to pretend that they were human. They did not know that Gaza is small, and that the picture would be recognized by
> the family. When the family returned to Khuza’a they found Ghalia
> dead!”*

The post from Avichay Adraee official account can also be found [here](https://twitter.com/AvichayAdraee/status/551018708143849473).

Comment: How are these two linked? The lady in the picture does not seem to be in wheelchair. The X (tweet) says '2015' and report is about incidents in 2014. Nor doe it verify that the soldier in picture would have been the perpetrator.

Comment: They are linked because both mentioned the woman name Ghalia Abu Reda and the post with giving her water. Also the report is indeed from 2015 not 2014. See this version of the same report with its date in the first page: https://undocs.org/Home/Mobile?FinalSymbol=A%2FHRC%2F29%2FCRP.4&Language=E&DeviceType=Desktop&LangRequested=False

Comment: No. It's describing incidents in 2014. See 'Ground operation' just above chapter 308.. Quote = July 2014 /quote

Comment: My take is that the tweet mistakenly dates the event in 2015 instead of 2014, but that it is referring to the same facts as in that answer.

Comment: However, the UN report collects testimony but doesn't offer further investigation into this specific case. I am afraid the precise circumstances of this woman's death will never be elucidated.

Comment: I agree. Anyway, the tweets do not mention anything about when did this happen instead they are citing when did Adraee posted the picture.

Comment: So, is this conclusive as to *whom* shot her? AFAICT the story was further disputed https://books.google.com/books?id=WyhoDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA87

Comment: I've rolled back the addition by Avery of [al-Aqsa TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Aqsa_TV). If the OP considers that a reliable source they can it themselves. Or Avery can answer with that as source themselves.

Comment: @pinegulf: the reason is that while she died in Aug 2014 by most accounts, Israel didn't release the photo with her receiving water until Jan 2015. That's also when the story that she had been shot seems to have been published for the first time. The earlier reports (see Jacob's answer) are far more vague as to her individual circumstances, although they appear to have been related to the fighting.

Comment: @Fizz Fair enough regarding dates. The two other questions are still open.

Answer (score 17):

This case is far from proven to the end.

No proof she was shot, and that it was from close range, or that it was intentional.

Finding a dead body in a place where intense fire exchanges took place doesn't prove an "execution".

Even the evidenceless UN report doesn't come to the conclusion that it was an execution of some sort.

Quote from Ir0's answer (Ir0 also asked the question): "The doctor who later examined the body told the witness that she had been shot from close range" - A witness reporting that some doctor said. Who is the doctor? An expert crime scene detective? Let him show his face and credentials.

For whom it might be interesting (I didn't verify everything in there): https://www.israellycool.com/2015/01/21/latest-palestinian-blood-libel-the-case-of-the-thirsty-old-woman/

> The only earlier mentions of her name are here [by al-Haq].
>
> > Khan Younis Governorate
> >
> > Morning – Evening Paramedics and civil defence forces recovered 10 bodies, including Ghalia Abu Rida and nine resistance fighters from the rubble of destroyed houses in Khuza’a and Absan al-Kabira. They were killed following the shelling of the area.
>
> And this from PCHR Gaza:
>
> > – In the morning, medical crews recovered the bodies of a woman and 9 members of Palestinian armed groups from the debris of destroyed homes in Khuza’a and ‘Abassan villages.  The woman was identified as Ghalia al-‘Abed Abu Raida.
>
> Here, her death is reported in connection with an IDF shelling of Khan Younis on August 3rd, and not a deliberate execution-style killing as is now being claimed.

The quote from PCHR can be [verified via archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811062221/http://www.pchrgaza.org/portal/en/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10562:on-the-28th-day-of-the-israeli-offensive-israeli-forces-redeploy-in-invaded-areas-in-the-gaza-strip-complete-neighborhoods-destroyed-11-palestinian-civilians-including-5-children-killed-by-israeli-bombardment-of-unrwa-shelter-in-rafah&catid=36:pchrpressreleases&Itemid=194). It's a report from August 4, 2014. And the same goes for the [al-Haq page/quote](https://web.archive.org/web/20140930194735/http://www.alhaq.org/documentation/weekly-focuses/821-al-haq-field-updates-from-the-gaza-strip), which however is reported for August 3; note that the current/live contents of that page is different from the one archived in 2014.

Comment: @Fizz, Seems like their whole site isn't responding. Maybe it's because the internet outages in Gaza... I'll try to look for others quoting them besides "israellycool".

Comment: The Israellycool link which cites PCHR, cites it as "In the morning, medical crews recovered the bodies of a woman and 9 members of Palestinian armed groups from the debris of destroyed homes in Khuza’a and ‘Abassan villages"  which clearly implies that the women and the 9 armed Palestinians where from multiple "destroyed homes" and two different villages (Khuza’a and ‘Abassan), how does this mean "sitting among 9 terrorists"?

Comment: I removed the 2nd part of the answer.

Comment: @Fizz, I provided the Israellycool link for whom it might be interesting, despite me not fact checking everything written there. You can vote him down on his website.

Comment: Actually, PCHR did mention it (can be verified via archive.org) as  "In the morning, medical crews recovered the bodies of a woman and 9 members of Palestinian armed groups from the debris of destroyed homes in Khuza'a and 'Abassan villages.  The woman was identified as Ghalia al-'Abed Abu Raida."  The date of the 'morning' referred seems to be 04 August 2014.

Comment: I've edited that into your answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Interestingly though, I can't verify the quote that Israellycool takes from alHaq. There is something there related "12:00 P.M. Dozens artillery shells struck Khuza’a and Absan al-Kabira. Many people who were heading back to their houses had to evacuate the area again due to the heavy shelling. 3:00 P.M [...] Three other bodies were recovered from Khuza’a." But it doesn't mention her by name.

Comment: And "11:00 A.M. Paramedics recovered 12 bodies, 11 of which belong to civilians, including four children, from the rubble of their homes in the eastern Rafah area: Ibtisam al-Mahmum, 18, Bisan al-Mahmum, 12, and her siblings ‘Abada al-Mahmum, 2, Heba al-Mahmum, 9, were killed in the shelling of al-Tannur neighbourhood. In addition to Radya Abu Omran, Fediya Abu Omran, Yunis Abu Omran, 24, who were found in rubble of their house in Tibet Zra’. In addition to, Ismail Ermelat, 20, Aseel Abu Muhsen, 18, Hammam Eshiban, 10." But the village of Abbasan isn't mentioned.

Comment: Alas, the earliest version of that al-Haq page found on archive.org is from 2021, so it's not impossible they've changed it after the 2015 controversy.

Comment: @Fizz, here's a 16 Jul 2014 version: https://web.archive.org/web/20140716185043/http://www.alhaq.org/documentation/weekly-focuses/821-al-haq-field-updates-from-the-gaza-strip

Comment: @lr0: I see, so their URL scheme changed. It would be more useful to get that page for August.

Comment: This is the only al-Haq URL I could find in the Israellycool story, which one are you referring to?

Comment: @lr0: I found it https://web.archive.org/web/20140930194735/http://www.alhaq.org/documentation/weekly-focuses/821-al-haq-field-updates-from-the-gaza-strip The old page does have "Morning – Evening Paramedics and civil defence forces recovered 10 bodies, including Ghalia Abu Rida and nine resistance fighters from the rubble of destroyed houses in Khuza’a and Absan al-Kabira. They were killed following the shelling of the area."

Comment: I'm rather unsure why this is getting DV after the details/quote I edited in. It's a reasonable point of uncertainty IMHO. Maybe tone down down the language in the earlier part? I loathe to change peoples words though (unlike adding quotes).

Comment: @Fizz This is a political topic... As much as one might hope the skeptics exchange to be full of people who examine things with a critical eye... The reality is that we (humans) use our intellect to justify our decisions. And reject anything that disagrees with our world view. Regardless of proof etc...

Comment: Asking about the identity and expertise of the doctor is reasonable. Saying, "Let him show his face and credentials." is combative and not constructive and should be edited out.